# Android Jenkins Builds

Tags: android, jenkins

I am developing Android apps on Windows platform. I can create and build android apps using command-line tools successfully on the local machine without a problem.

I decided to use Jenkins to build apps remotely. I could succefully created a windows slave and created a test app using command line tools. But I can't get it to be emulated remotely with this :

```
C:\Dev\workspace\com.this.test\cordova\cordova.bat
```

This line works locally, but if I use it on Jenkins, it produces this error.

```
c:\Dev\jenkins\workspace\buildtest>C:\Dev\workspace\com.this.test\cordova\cordova.bat emulate 
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

You don't have any Android Virtual Devices. Please create at least one AVD.
android
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
```

**EDIT:**
If I run the following command locally,

```
%comspec% /c android.bat list avd
```

it lists the AVDs like below.

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: ap16
    Path: C:\Users\tt\.android\avd\ap16.avd
  Target: Android 4.1.2 (API level 16)
     ABI: armeabi-v7a
    Skin: WVGA800
```

But if I send it via Jenkins it says nothing but :

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an emulator on the remote machine? i.e. Via the `android create avd` command line, or using the SDK Manager tool.

More simply, you can also install the [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) to automatically handle creation of emulators.

---

**Edit, after more info was provided:**

Emulators created are per-user — they're not shared between all users of a machine.

Presumably you're running Jenkins as a different user, e.g. the system user by running Jenkins as a Windows service.  Therefore it sees a different set of emulators as you do when logged in to your account.

I would still recommend using the [emulator plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin), so that Jenkins can create its own emulators when it needs to (though note the "Known Issues" about running as a Windows system account). Alternatively, you can probably create the emulators manually as the Jenkins account, or change the Jenkins service to "run as" your regular user.

Comment: No, I didn't create anything additional. But there is an AVD already available. If I run `%comspec% /c android.bat list avd` command locally on the slave, it list the available AVD. But if I send this command via Jenkins, it says nothing found, I am really confused. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Android Emulator plugin, but I also faced issue with the latest version of this plugin and there is no option to downgrade it.
I tried to create virtual device in Jenkins and also tried to use existing virtual device - errors in both cases...